# Equally many cards between aces

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the probability that in a set of $52$ cards, there will be equally many cards between each ace?

I tried this problem, but I am stuck. I know that there are $52!$ possible cases.

If there are $k$ cards between each ace, than this would be likely event $\{A,k,A,k,A,k,A\}$. There is $4!$ ways to permute these aces, and cards between them $k!\cdot k!\cdot k!\cdot 3$, so that is $3\cdot 4!\cdot (k!)^3$ likely events. Another likely case would be $\{m,A,k,A,k,A,k,A\}$. Here it would be $4!\cdot (48-m)!\cdot 3$.

Total number of likely events would be  $$\frac{3\cdot 4!\cdot (k!)^3+4!\cdot (48-m)!\cdot 3}{52!}$$

Of course, this cannot be right, because I have m and k in expression so it is not good. Where am I making mistake? And if there is some easier approach could you explain it in detail so I could really understand what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Asterisks are for *\*italics\**. Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

It is much easier to segregate the deck into aces and non-aces and to think of choosing the positions for the aces.  There are $52 \choose 4$ ways to place the aces.  The successful placings are defined by the position of the first ace and the number of cards between aces.  If the first ace comes at position $1$ there are $17$ ways to choose the positions of the aces because you can have $0$ to $16$ cards between each pair.  If the first ace comes at positions $2$ through $4$ you have $16$ choices, if the first ace comes at positions $5$ through $7$ you have $15$ choices and so on until if the first comes at positions $47$ to $49$ you have only one choice.  The number of successes is then $17 + 3\sum_{i=1}^{16}i=17+3\cdot \frac 12 \cdot 16 \cdot 17=425$ and the probability is $\frac {425}{52 \choose 4}=\frac 1{637}$

Comment: I think the very first part is wrong and only if the first ace is in the first position are there 17 choices. 1-Ace-16-Ace-16-Ace-16-Ace is 53 cards. Then positions 2 to 4 have 16 choices, 5 to 7 have 15 choices, ..., 47 to 49 have one choice. (Note $3\nmid(49-2)$ but $3\mid(49-1))$

Comment: @nickgard:  you are right, I was off by $1$.  Fixed.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Think of the deck as a binary string in which $1$ denotes an ace, e.g.: $$000100...00100...00100...001000000$$

*Every* binary string of this form represents exactly $4!48!$ different possible decks, so we can confidently use this representation to calculate probabilities.

There are $52\choose 4$ such strings.

If the aces are all together as $1111$, then there can be between $0$ and $48$ cards before them in the deck. That makes $49$ arrangements.

If the aces are one card apart as $1010101$, there can be between $0$ and $45$ cards before them in the deck. That makes $46$ arrangements.

If the aces are two cards apart, there are $43$ arrangements, etc., decreasing by $3$ each time.

Therefore the answer is $$\frac{49+46+43+...+7+4+1}{52\choose 4}$$

Now there are $17$ terms on top (since $49=1+3\cdot 16$), so (adding $2$ to each term),$$\begin{align*}&\ \ 1+4+7+...+49\\=\quad&(3+6+9+...+51)-2\cdot 17\\=\quad&3(1+2+3+...+17)-34\\=\quad&3\tbinom{18}2-34\\=\quad &425\end{align*}$$

The final answer is $\frac{425}{270725}=\frac1{637}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Amazing approach. I just have one question, why are there 52C4 such strings?

Comment: Basically you start with a string of 52 zeros, and then flip 4 of them into ones to represent aces. So you have 52 and choose 4: which is $\tbinom{52}4$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a deep breath and do this is steps.

First how many different number of cards apart can the aces be?

The Aces can be consecutive, i.e one card apart with zero cards between them, up to $17$ cards apart with 16 cards between between them.  (e.g. the first, 18th, 35rd, and 52th cards are aces.)

So there are $\sum_\limits{n= 1}^{17} f(n)$ ways where $f(n)$ is the number of ways to do it with $n$ cards between.

Next.  How many different positions can we place the aces.  If $n= 1$ the aces can be in the any $k... (k+3)$ position as long as $k \ge 1$ and $k + 3 \le 52$.  In other words there are $49$ positions.   If $n= 17$ the first ace can only be in the first position and the last ace can only be in the last position

If $k$ is the position of the first ace, then $k + 3*n$ is the position of the last ace $k \ge 1$ and $k + 3n \le 52$ so $k \le 52 - 3n$ so there are $52-3n$ possible sets of positions to place the aces.

So there are $\sum_\limits{n= 1}^{17} \sum_\limits{k= 1}^{52-3n}g(n,k)$ ways where $g(n,k)$ are the ways to arrange cards with $n$ cards apart starting at position $k$.

[i.e. $f(n) = \sum_\limits{k= 1}^{52-3n}g(n,k)$.]

Given that the aces are in four position there are $4!$ ways to arrange the aces.  The remaining ways to place the $48$ remaining cards are $48!$ ways.

So $g(n,k) = 4!48!$, a constant value.

So there are $\sum_\limits{n= 1}^{17} \sum_\limits{k= 1}^{52-3n}g(n,k)=\sum_\limits{n= 1}^{17} \sum_\limits{k= 1}^{52-3n}4!48! = 4!48!\sum_\limits{n= 1}^{17} \sum_\limits{k= 1}^{52-3n}1 = 4!48!\sum_\limits{n=1}^{17}52-3n=$

$4!48(52*17 - 3*\sum_\limits{n=1}^{17} n)=$

$4!48!(52*17 - 3*\frac {17*18}2)=$

$4!48!17(52- 3*9)=$

$4!48!17*25$.

I hope.  If I didn't make any arithmetic errors.

Probability is $\frac {4!48!17*25}{52!} = \frac {4!*17*25}{49*50*51*52}= \frac {4!}{49*2*3*52} = \frac {1}{49*13}$

Hmm, Actually as we were doing probability, maybe I should have ignored the ways to arrange the aces and the rest of the cards and and only work on the positions.

The reasoning would be similar.  There will be $\sum_\limits{n= 1}^{17} \sum_\limits{k= 1}^{52-3n}1 = 17*25$ positions to place the 4 aces. so probability is $\frac {17*25}{{52 \choose 4}} = \frac {17*25*4!}{49*50*51*52}=\frac {1}{49*13}$

Another way to see it is:  The $4$ aces with $m$ cards between them will take up $4 + 3*m$ spaces.  That leaves $52 - (4 + 3m) = 48-3m$ spaces to go before, and/or after the four aces. There will be $48 - 3m + 1$ places to put the first ace.  So there are $\sum_{m=0}^{16} 49- 3m= 17*49 - 3*\frac{16*17}2 = 17*(49- 24) = 17*25 = 425$ ways to do this.